# Linear transformation of rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was doing exercises for my algebra class and i stucked. I have to check wheter the L transformation is linear. With transformation like for eg. $\Bbb R^3 → \Bbb R^3, L(x,y,z) =(3x+2y-z,z+x,5y-7z)$ i don't have any troubles. Problems start for example this one: : $L: \Bbb R^2 → \Bbb R^2$, where $L$ is a rotation by angle $\frac{\pi}{4}$ relative to $(0,0)$. How to check if given tranformation is linear?

Comment: Think of the matrix which represents a rotation of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ of a vector $(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

The rotation by angle $\theta$ can be written as (draw it if you need):
\begin{align*}
L_{\theta}(x,y) = (\cos(\theta)x - \sin(\theta)y,\sin(\theta)x + \cos(\theta)y)
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?